# .net ASCX help with passining info & Hiding Div

Tags: c#, .net, ascx

Alright, I am trying to accomplish this: When a user clicks a button that is on a ascx web user control with text boses, it first displays a DIV that is hidden, this div contains a ascx web user control. Basically I want that web user control to grab what they typed in the boxes on the first web user control, and then apply to a SQL search from what the users type in the text boxes on the first page. Is this possible or do I need to rethink my strategy on this? I am programming in c# for the SQL statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

You can define properties of the control which accepts the text input, and expose the values using direct field access, variables, or session variables; you can then use `FindControl` from within the newly displayed control, and, if found, utilise the now exposed properties to gather the values required.

For instance, your input control code-behind might look something like this:

```
partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public string MyFieldValue
    {
        get { return MyFieldTextBox.Text; }
    }
}
```

And in the next control, to use it, a little like this:

```
partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myControl = Page.FindControl("MyControlInstanceName") as MyControl;
        if (myControl != null)
        {
            var myFieldValue = myControl.MyFieldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the 2nd user control embedded in the 1st or not?

If not, you can make anything available upwards between user controls by simply adding public properties to your user controls. This means they can then be accessed from the page level or the containing user control. For example, if I have UCA, UCB, UCC

UCA contains UCB and UCC is hidden.

UCB has the following property

```
public string UserEnteredName
{
   get { return NameTextBox.Text; }
}
```

UCC has the following property and method

```
public string UserEnteredName { get; set; }

public BindResults()
{
    UserEnteredLiteral.Text = UserEnteredName;
}
```

Then tie it together with UCA:

```
protected MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UCC.UserEnteredName = UCB.UserEnteredName;
... some logic herre.
    UCC.BindResults();
}
```

You can also raise an event from UCB that can be responded to in UCA if your button or submit action exists in UCB.

Comment: Yes the 2nd user control is embedded in the first one.

Comment: Yep, then just setting public properties on the control is probably a better way to go. Findcontrol will work, but does mean you'll only find problems with it at runtime, not build time. Especially if you change the type of control it is.

Comment: You can even set the controld directly with Public string MyProperty { set { MyTextbox.Text = val; } }